# How to resolve a Google email error "The SMTP server requires secure connection or the client was not authenticated" when using an app password?

Tags: authentication, smtp, gmail

I have this code for sending emails from an ASP.NET Core app in Visual Studio 2022:

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("5quillas@gmail.com");
var fromPassword = "xxxxxxxxx";
var toAddress = new MailAddress("e@hotmail.com");

string subject = "subject";
string body = "body";

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    Timeout = 10000,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};

using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})

smtp.Send(message);
```

I have already made the Gmail account use 2-step verification, and get an app password, which I am using in the code above, but I get an SMTP error:

> 5.7.0 user not autheticated

I am using the account for email verification for new users.

Any ideas?